# How to use a loop while defining subplots in matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

As an exercise, I was trying to analyse and visualize the following data.
http://www.calvin.edu/~stob/data/Berkeley.csv
I managed to achieve what I had in mind but my code seems very repetitive. 
Is there any way to achieve the following in fewer lines of code?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv(""ucb.csv")

df_male = df[df['Gender'] == 'Male']
df_female = df[df['Gender'] == 'Female']

dmd = pd.pivot_table(df_male, values="Freq", index = 'Dept', 
columns='Admit')
dfd = pd.pivot_table(df_female, values="Freq", index = 'Dept', 
columns='Admit')
ddm = pd.pivot_table(df_male, values="Freq", index = 'Admit', 
columns='Dept')
ddf = pd.pivot_table(df_female, values="Freq", index = 'Admit', 
columns='Dept')

ma, mb, mc, md, me, mf = list(ddm['A']), list(ddm['B']), list(ddm['C']), 
list(ddm['D']), list(ddm['E']), list(ddm['F'])
fa,fb,fc,fd,fe,ff=list(ddf['A']),list(ddf['B']),list(ddf['C']),
list(ddf['D']),list(ddf['E']),list(ddf['F'])

a,b,c,d = dmd['Admitted'].sum(), dmd['Rejected'].sum(), 
dfd['Admitted'].sum(), dfd['Rejected'].sum()

males = "Accepted Vs Rejected ratio for " + str(a+b) + " Men"
females = "Accepted Vs Rejected ratio for " + str(c+d) + " Women"
male_ratio = [a,b]
female_ratio = [c,d]
labels = "Accepted", "Rejected"

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,18))
axm = fig.add_subplot(3,6,1)  
axm.title.set_text(males)
axf = fig.add_subplot(3,6,4)
axf.title.set_text(females)
axma = fig.add_subplot(3,6,7)
axma.title.set_text("Dept A Men")
axmb = fig.add_subplot(3,6,8)
axmb.title.set_text("Dept B Men")
axmc = fig.add_subplot(3,6,9)
axmc.title.set_text("Dept C Men")
axmd = fig.add_subplot(3,6,10)
axmd.title.set_text("Dept D Men")
axme = fig.add_subplot(3,6,11)
axme.title.set_text("Dept E Men")
axmf = fig.add_subplot(3,6,12)
axmf.title.set_text("Dept F Men")
axfa = fig.add_subplot(3,6,13)
axfa.title.set_text("Dept A Women")
axfb = fig.add_subplot(3,6,14)
axfb.title.set_text("Dept B Women")
axfc = fig.add_subplot(3,6,15)
axfc.title.set_text("Dept C Women")
axfd = fig.add_subplot(3,6,16)
axfd.title.set_text("Dept D Women")
axfe = fig.add_subplot(3,6,17)
axfe.title.set_text("Dept E Women")
axff = fig.add_subplot(3,6,18)
axff.title.set_text("Dept F Women")
axm.pie(male_ratio, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
axf.pie(female_ratio, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
axma.pie(ma, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
axmb.pie(mb, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
axmc.pie(mc, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
axmd.pie(md, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
axme.pie(me, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
axmf.pie(mf, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
axfa.pie(fa, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
axfb.pie(fb, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
axfc.pie(fc, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
axfd.pie(fd, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
axfe.pie(fe, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
axff.pie(ff, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
```

Here is the output that I got: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4G0mI.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating different data frames for each gender you can combine them into one data frame by providing multiple indices. This allows you to use a nested for-loop to create a pie-chart for each department/gender combination, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("ucb.csv")

pivot = df.pivot_table(values="Freq", index = ['Gender', 'Admit'], columns=['Dept'])

# add a column with the total counts over all departments
pivot['total'] = pivot.sum(1)

male_ratio = pivot['total']['Male']
female_ratio = pivot['total']['Female']

males = f"Accepted Vs Rejected ratio for {int(male_ratio.sum())} Men"
females = f"Accepted Vs Rejected ratio for {int(female_ratio.sum())} Women"

labels = "Accepted", "Rejected"

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,18))
axm = fig.add_subplot(3,6,1)
axm.title.set_text(males)
axf = fig.add_subplot(3,6,4)
axf.title.set_text(females)
axm.pie(male_ratio, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
axf.pie(female_ratio, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')

offset = 7
for gender, label in zip(("Male", "Female"), ('Men', 'Women')):
    for dept in 'ABCDEF':
        ax = fig.add_subplot(3, 6, offset)
        ax.title.set_text(f'Dept {dept} {label}')
        ax.pie(pivot[dept][gender], labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
        offset += 1
```